# Check are two columns of a datafrane are in the defined order. Reverse orders if it's different and do calculations on the third column

Tags: pandas

Hi I have a dataframe that I'd like to check is the column `group1` higher than `group2` on the same row. In the below example, row 2 does not follow the order because `Low` < `High`. Row3  also doesn't follow the order.

For the rows that do not follow the order, I'd like to reverse the order and the `score`. For row2, the score will be `(1 - 0.8) + 1 = 1.2`

```
d = {'score':[1.1, 0.8, 0.7], 'group1':['High', 'Low', 'Mid'], 'group2':['Low', 'High', 'High']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dd
```

```
score   group1  group2
1.1     High    Low
0.8     Low     High
0.7     Mid     High
```

Expected output:

```
score   group1  group2 score_revise group1_revise group2_revise
1.1     High    Low    1.1          High          Low   
0.8     Low     High   1.2          High          Low
0.7     Mid     High   1.3          High          Mid
```

I probably can achieve this by writing many if statements, but I wonder there are smarter ways.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many records you have, but it can be handled by looping, see [df.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

```
for idx,row in dd.iterrows():
    # print(idx, row)
    if row.group1 == 'High':
        dd.loc[idx,'score_revise'] = row.score
        dd.loc[idx,'group1_revise'] = row.group1
        dd.loc[idx,'group2_revise'] = row.group2        
    else:
        dd.loc[idx,'score_revise'] = (1 - row.score) + 1
        dd.loc[idx,'group1_revise'] = row.group2
        dd.loc[idx,'group2_revise'] = row.group1  


  dd

    score   group1  group2  score_revise    group1_revise   group2_revise
0   1.1     High    Low     1.1     High    Low
1   0.8     Low     High    1.2     High    Low
2   0.7     Mid     High    1.3     High    Mid
```